# Eclipse IAutoEditStrategy only called on backspace; how to have it called on all edits?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am currently working on a custom editor plugin for Eclipse. I've overwritten getAutoEditStrategies like this:

```
public IAutoEditStrategy[] getAutoEditStrategies(
  ISourceViewer sourceViewer, String contentType) {
  return new IAutoEditStrategy[] { new KRLAutoEditStrategy() };
}
```

and written a minimal Strategy like this:

```
public class KRLAutoEditStrategy implements IAutoEditStrategy {
  public void customizeDocumentCommand(IDocument d, DocumentCommand c) {
    System.out.println("Called.");
  }
}
```

Now customizeDocumentCommand is only called when I hit backspace, not for any other character. What am I missing? How else do I implement auto indention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figured this one out myself now. My strategy was perfectly fine but it didn't work because the editor partition I wanted it to be applied to was not exposed through `getConfiguredContentTypes`.

When your coloring or indention doesn't work, make sure that you work on a partition which has the correct tokens applied to it and exposed through `getConfiguredContentTypes`! The problem became obvious when I used distinct colors for all partitions and one of them didn't get colored.

Answer (score 1):

Can't see anything wrong with your custom strategy (almost the same code works fine for me), but to implement some basic kind of auto indention you can use `DefaultIndentLineAutoEditStrategy` (add it to the array returned by `getAutoEditStrategies`)